# Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, uber-api

I do not understand why I am getting this error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

I have tried both:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

This is the full error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116430:34)
at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:131184:44
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:131159:49)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:150357:87)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:150318:36)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:150212:37)
at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:115251:49)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5952:25)
at Object.491 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:2405:109)
```

*Ionic Framework*: **3.9.2**
*Ionic Native*: **^2.9.0**
*Ionic App Scripts*: **3.2.4**
*Angular Core*: **5.2.11**
*Angular Compiler CLI*: **5.2.11**
*Node*: **8.10.0**
*OS*: **Windows 10**

Answer (score 9):

You need import HttpClientModule, example:

```
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
     HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
     AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Read: [Angula HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)